# Paypal IPN Sending Custom variables for the callback

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I need to send some custom variables like product ID to PayPal. I need this custom travel through the payment process and be passed to my IPN callback URL.

I cant find anywhere how to send custom variables from the basket that can then be retrieved in my call back URL.

How could I do that?

Comment: https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference

Comment: I need the html mark up to be able to send custom variables to paypal and then get those variables back on the callback

Comment: There is tons of information: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/#id09BLDK0007Q https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: none of the info tells you if it is possible to do what i need.

Comment: @EJP thats an interesting technique can attach vars in the notify_url like this http://yoururl.com/notify?p_id=whatever&cat_id=another

Answer (score 0):

The field you're looking for is `CUSTOM` (at least under NVP) and will be passed back in any IPN calls made regarding that payment. You can see it in [this call](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 'custom' variable, you can also add any arguments you like (as long as they don't conflict with IPN variables) to the notify_url. This technique works best when you supply the notify_url in the form itself.